# Images respecting top margin regardless of size

Tags: css

In my photo gallery app, when the user clicks on a photo from the gallery it is displayed in full view. The issue I am having is that when setting the margin for every image that is displayed in full view, the margin that appears is different depending on the actual size of the image.

What I want to happen is that (regardless of the image size), I want the top margin to be respected so that the image is displayed with the top starting at the same point on the page for every image. If the image is too large then I would like it to force a a scroll bar to appear.

I have set the margin-top to 40px but on the larger image, it is displayed too far up the page (see images below).

[image]

The image above is where I would like all images to start on the page

[image]

The image above has the same margin set as the one above that but as you can see, the starting point at the top of the page is not the desired place.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image-full-view" [ngStyle]="{'height': selectedImage.heightSize, 'width': selectedImage.widthSize}" [src]="selectedImage.imagePath" alt="Man Praying">
</div>
<div class="image-name-container">
    <p class="image-name">{{ selectedImage.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.image-full-view {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
     -moz-transform: scale(1.5); 
      -ms-transform: scale(1.5); 
       -o-transform: scale(1.5); 
          transform: scale(1.5);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9999619230641713, M12=-0.008726535498373935, M21=0.008726535498373935, M22=0.9999619230641713,SizingMethod='auto expand');  
            border: solid 5px black;    

}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    border: solid 5px black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Try `transform-origin:top;` on `.image-full-view `

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work. I implemented the code exactly as you explained but when loading different sized images (different heights) the starting position of the tops of the images are not all the same

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the issues is caused due to the transform:scale(1.5) css property. Kindly remove it and achieve the same by multiplying 1.5 with selectedImage.heightSize and selectedImage.widthSize.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Increasing the margin-top doesn't resolve the issue as the various sized images still all start at different heights on the page (same as my original issue). Setting a max height isn't an option for me as the heights will be pre-determined to ensure the photos are displayed the way I want them to be.

Comment: can you try adding the margin-top:200px inside the .image-container class .

Comment: Thanks for responding. This still has the same issue i'm afraid

Comment: using the transform:scale(1.5) css property is causing the issue. can this be removed ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the problem either. The original problem still remains